# Angular CLI Monorepo: using 'ng serve' inside project directory serves default project instead

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We have set up an Angular CLI monorepo structure with several Angular 8 projects. We're having a problem where using commands like 'ng serve' or 'ng build' inside of the project directories (instead of at the root level) does not serve, build, etc. the project we're currently inside of. Instead, the project that is built is the `defaultProject` that is specified in the `angular.json` config.

Is it possible to run a command like `ng serve` inside of a project directory and have the command run against the current-level project rather than the default project? I can't think of a way other than have a `pakcage.json` with npm scripts to handle the commands, but that may not be maintainable as we add more projects.

Comment: You should be running `ng serve projectname`

Comment: That's our fallback plan, which is fine, we're just hoping there's a way we can have angular detect the context of the project for these commands.

Comment: What's the problem with running `ng serve projectname` and why is this a fallback plan whilst it's the main way to deal with it?

Comment: Just in terms of convention - when our developers are working on a project, they have a terminal open to that project directory, not at the root level. So when they want to do `ng serve`, they may not think about adding the project name. Then there's a problem because it's serving the wrong project (thanks to the defaultProject setting).

Comment: The question is less "what should we be doing" and more "why don't commands like `ng serve` work this way". More of a curiosity than anything.